# Is this contrast readable?

Tags: accessibility, legibility, contrast

On [**this oh-so-slowly-developing page**](http://www.sellmycalls.com/cgi-bin/chain), there is the column headed "Bid x Ask", which reflects the numbers of bids and offers on the stock option in the row:

[image: Screenshot of application]

Are the numbers here readable? How can I improve the readability?

Comment: Also try [graphic design SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the colours paler, keep the text black and don't have a dividing line between the two colours. + Make the table size bigger on Chrome - the text is TINY!

[image]

Comment: ok. thanks. because nobody will be able to quickly see the diff between pale blue and pale green, I'll have to give in and make the green be pale red instead. or whatever contrasts best with pale blue. that also solves the blue-green colorblind accessibility issue, which the dividing line was for. ok, good. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Which is more important, the 55x55 number or the bar graph behind it? Right now they are competing equally so neither is winning and you're ending up with mud. De-emphasize one or the other.

In addition, perhaps you don't need them overlapping. The bar graph could be a lot thinner and perhaps under the text:

```
34 x 93894
======--------
```

Comment: yeah, you're right, it's mud. and that's exactly my worry. the numbers and the graph are (I *believe*, not really sure) equally important. the bar graph for the user's quick feel for what's going on with this option right now; and the numbers because -- well, because they're the *numbers*, man! So I guess the bars are more imp. The numbers are on a tooltip anyway, and maybe they should just stay there. How about that? I'm beginning to like the idea of a 2px or 3px line under to represent the bars. Or maybe I hack together a 2-color border.

Answer (score 1):

From the screen shot they look OK, but the text on the actual page is far too small.

The only thing I would say it so increase the contrast between the foreground and background colours to make the numbers stand out more.

You might try black text with more faded colours as the background.

Comment: thanks! yes, I tried that but then the black text draws attention away from and so obscures the bar chart that underlies the text.

Answer (score 1):

Use the combination of warm and cool colors for bid X ask, [Color Theory](http://www.tigercolor.com/color-lab/color-theory/color-theory-intro.htm) and set screen minimum resolution to 1024 X 768.  the table is now looking very small its hard for -1 people to view it.